# How do I make my javascript code for adding a new class to HTML more responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="control">
  <input
    type="email"
    id="email"
    class="email-address"
    onblur="getValEmail()"
  />
  <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
<div class="control box">
  <textarea id="message" onblur="getValMsg()"></textarea>
  <label for="message">message</label>
</div>



function getValEmail() {
  const valEmail = document.getElementById("email");

  valEmail.addEventListener("blur", function () {
    if (valEmail.value) valEmail.parentElement.classList.add("filled");
    else valEmail.parentElement.classList.remove("filled");
  });
}

function getValMsg() {
  const valMsg = document.getElementById("message");

  valMsg.addEventListener("blur", function () {
    if (valMsg.value) valMsg.parentElement.classList.add("filled");
    else valMsg.parentElement.classList.remove("filled");
  });
}


.filled label,
input:focus + label,
textarea:focus + label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

These are HTML, Javascript and CSS codes in order.
What I'm trying to achieve here is that once user writes email address/message, labels that are inside of input/textarea go up. So, when input/textarea are filled up, labels should disappear to the top. It does its job but not responsively. "filled" class is added after a couple of more clicks happen, which means that labels only go up to the top after I click the box again.

[image]

Result looks like this.

[image]

This is only achieved after a few more clicks in the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `js` here at all. The `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class will do what you actually need to achieve (note the non-empty `placeholder` attrs required for chrome):

```css
.control {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input+label,
textarea+label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 300ms;
}

input:focus+label,
input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
textarea:focus+label,
textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <input type="email" id="email" class="email-address" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
<div class="control box">
  <textarea id="message" placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <label for="message">message</label>
</div>
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/VwyBdOE).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for a new concept. I didn't even know the existence of placeholder-shown! I'll look into it. However, do you know why the class "filled" is not added responsively in my code? Apparently, when I use "onfocus" instead of "onblur", the class is added immediately.

Comment: Please use the Stacksnippet (`Ctrl + M` or the `<>`-Button) to provide code that can be run. Then there is rarely a case where you need to use a codepen or simliar.

Comment: Your `blur` event handler attached via `.addEventListener` is not actually beeing run at the first `blur` event (it is only beeing attached there), only after the second one. But with every consequent `blur` event this handler is beeing attached again and again. After an n-th event it will be run n-1 times. You don't need the `onblur` attributes nor the corresponding functions. Just drop your `addEventListener` into the `<script>` tag and that's enough in this case.

Comment: @tacoshy, sure will try that next time, ty.

Answer (score -1):

In your css use:
transform:translateY(-2em)
change accordingly to your adjustment.